# not (max-width: 512px) not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I have the following HTML page:

```
<style>
  @media not(max-width: 512px) { * { color: red; } }
</style>

Foobar
```

However, this is unresponsive to the window's `width`. The media rule is never applied. If I remove the `not`, it works as expected. What do I not understand about `not(max-width)`?

Yes, I know there are other ways to accomplish the same thing, and `not(max-width: 512px)` is the same as `min-width: 513px` and so on. However, for the system I am building I need to be able to specify `not(max-width)`.

Comment: `not` goes only with media type `media_query: [[only | not]? <media_type> [ and <expression> ]*]`

Comment: Here's an article about what @Justinas said https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/ Relevant quote from Chris "Just doing not (max-width: 600px) doesn't seem to work for me, hence the slightly funky syntax above."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the following media query:

```css
@media not all and (max-width: 512px) {
  * { 
    color: red;
  } 
}
```

```html
<span>Foobar</span>
```

On the CSS specification, you can find the following [syntax for media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax). You can see the `NOT` isn't allowed directly in front of the expression:

```
: [ONLY | NOT]? S* media_type S* [ AND S* expression ]* 
| expression [ AND S* expression ]*
;
```